# Functionality in a Dependency of type=pom

Tags: maven

If I have a POM that contains a dependency of type=POM, e.g.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-starter</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I see that the included POM can contain other dependencies, thus providing a way to package together a set of related dependencies.

Can the reference POM also contain build steps? 
For example: Use the resource plugin to copy certain files that are needed when using the specific JAR mentioned in its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies of type `pom` may contain some `build` configuration information (such as `resources`,  `plugins` or `pluginManagement`) but any of them will be executed for the current project but if you configure the pom of the current project to invoke them.

In fact, only the current pom and the parent pom of the current project define in the `build` element the build information/taks of the current project.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by configuring the pom to invoke things that are in the dependent poms, please?

Comment: Sure. I don't have the time now but I will give you a clear example to illustrate that later.